# Android : How to use flurry API

Tags: android, flurry

I am using flurry in my app, and I am new to that. I have some doubts.

My requirement is, In my main activity I will start a session, and calling onevent method in some activities. And I am not calling endSeesion method anywhere. I want to know when the FlurryAgent will hit the flurry site.

1. So do I need to call endSession then where should I call that method?
2. How FlurryAgent maintains the session.
3. In case if I call like this

   ```
   FlurryAgent.onEndSession(this);
   FlurryAgent.onStartSession(this, Constants.FLURRY_API);        
   FlurryAgent.setLogEnabled(true);
   ```

   will it work like this - previous session will be closed and new session will be started.
4. I can track only http urls using fiddler, when I try to track https calls then its getting crashed, I have modified ssl settings in fiddler, I dont know how to configure my emulator.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot easily use flurry for analytics with the android emulator, you have use analytics like Includeapp API, or medialts. I spent quite some times fiddling with flurry, got frustrated as I did not see any data on the dashboard.